# Right click on a subgrid missing the "Open in a New Window" option

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

When I right click a row in a subgrid on a form, I sometimes see the option *Open in a New Window*, while this option at other times is missing.

I do not see a pattern in when *Open in a New Window* is available and when it is not. On some forms it works, while on others it does not work.

Right click menu without *Open in a New Window*:

[image: Right click on subgrid row without "Open in a New Window"]

Right click menu with *Open in a New Window*:

[image: Right click on subgrid row with "Open in a New Window"]

I have tried with both Chrome and Internet Explorer. Both browsers show the same intermittent behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior seems to be as follows:

- If the first subgrid on your form is inside a collapsed tab when the form is loaded, *Open in a New Window* will not be available on any subgrids on the given form.
- If, on the other hand, the first subgrid on the form is inside an expanded tab when the form is loaded, *Open in a New Window* works fine on all subgrids. This also works even if the expanded tab is set to not be visible.

Comment: Sounds like the CRM I know :)